# NFS Stale mounts logging and tracing

Tags: linux, logging, nfs, mount, trace

We have a large filesystem exported via **NFS** and mounted to several Linux Servers.
These mounts seem to go stale for some seconds during the last days making the apps using those mounts to freeze.

While trying to troubleshoot the issue we see no errors in NFS server(except of a CPU spike at the time of the issue), nor in the NFS clients. We looked primarily into the /var/log files.

Is there any way to troubleshoot the issue in retrospect, especially something like a **log** or **trace**? Except of nfs-utils package (nfsstat, nfsiostat) which could be used at the time the issue happens, I could not find any other way to troubleshoot the issue after it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on traffic, you can collect nfs traffic capture to identify unexpected errors or behaviour. You can configure a rolling capture and always keep some number of files to analyse. The example blow will keep 10 files 10MB each:

```
dumpcap -i any -f "port 2049" -w /tmp/nfs.pcap -b filesize:10000 -b files:10
```